# esp32 SemaphoreTake vs SemaphoreTakeFromISR

Tags: c, semaphore, interrupt, esp32, freertos

i want to have a task to calibrate xh711 on esp32. This task has to be triggered either buy button from iSR or by the program on initial start if needed.

On button press i have to user xSemaphoreGiveFromISR() but on automated call from program i can use xSemaphoreGive()

My question is which function should i use to identify the trigger? It is clear that for the button i have to use the xSemaphoreTakeFromISR() but on the automated trigger by the program should i use the xSemaphoreTake() or i can use the ISR version also with no problem?

Comment: You need to understand that the ‘FromISR’ API calls are dedicated to be used in ISRs only i.e. are called from ISRs. The API without the FromISR tag has to be used in tasks.

Comment: SO on task where i wait for the semaphore i should not use the TakeFromISR but only the normal Take()

Comment: Exactly. That’s right.

Comment: @kyrpav If my answer was helpful, I would appreciate it if you could also upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions ending in `FromISR` can be called from the interrupt service routine. The regular functions can only be used from task context.

See the documentation of [xSemaphoreGive](https://www.freertos.org/a00123.html) and [xSemaphoreGiveFromISR](https://www.freertos.org/a00124.html).

There are several reasons for having separate functions, for example:

- Non-ISR functions need to use [critical sections](https://www.freertos.org/taskENTER_CRITICAL_taskEXIT_CRITICAL.html).
- ISR functions have a parameter `pxHigherPriorityTaskWoken` used for context switching.
- Some non-ISR functions have `xTicksToWait` parameter to allow the task to sleep while it waits for a resource to become available. ISR functions do not have this parameter as ISRs cannot be blocked.